# How do I make full use of a generic 6-button mouse?

Tags: snow-leopard, mouse, keybindings

Somebody gave me a 6-mouse button. I want to make full use of the extra buttons as opposed to just using the basic 3 ones (left, on-scroller, and right buttons). First of all, I want to know where the buttons on the mouse are mapped to currently. I'm having trouble finding an app that will let me see what functionality they are mapped in. Next is how do I actually remap them?

I'm on Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

Comment: Does the vendor have a Mac driver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a tool like [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Information.html) to map various functions to the buttons on your generic 6-button mouse.

Comment: It doesn't detect the 6th button (the one below the scroller). Only the two buttons on the side but I guess that's better than nothing. Thanks!

Comment: From my experience, that button beneath the scroll bar is usually a DPI toggle switch?

Comment: Nah, I don't think it's hooked to any function at all.

Comment: @BoShubinsky Thanks for that hint. I didn`t even know something like that exists.

Answer (score 3):

yeah the button above or below the scroll is the adjustment of DPI of the mouse. mine is 4 types. if you click the 6th button then play on your cursor on the screen each click (6th button)you will notice the ranges how far can your cursor travel from left to right or up/down.

Answer (score -1):

The 6th button bellow the scroll button is to toggle the movement of curser.